# Error deserializing JSON with Newtonsoft, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, json

I'm receiving the following error:

> ```
> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ReportingDataSchema.CurrentBusinessUnits]]' 
> because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly. 
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. 
> JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path 'selectedBusinessUnits', line 1, position 26."} System.Exception {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException}
> ```

My JSON:

```js
{
  "selectedBusinessUnits": [{
    "guidNode": "some value",
    "businessUnit": "some value",
    "fileName": "some value"
  }, {
    ...
  }]
}
```

I'm trying to first transform this response into the following:

```c#
public class EnAFileGenerator
{
    private Dictionary<string, List<CurrentBusinessUnits>> selectedBusinessUnits;

    public Dictionary<string, List<CurrentBusinessUnits>> SelectedBusinessUnits 
    {
        get { return selectedBusinessUnits; }
        set { selectedBusinessUnits = value; }
    }
}
```

So that ultimately I can access the array in the JSON, using the following:

```c#
public class CurrentBusinessUnits
{
    private string guidNode;
    private string businessUnit;
    private string fileName;

    public string GuidNode { get; set; }
    public string BusinessUnit { get; set; }        
    public string FileName { get; set; }       
}
```

The code that's generating the error:

```
// JSON Data is the parameter from the client, containing the above JSON object
EnAFileGenerator resultArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EnAFileGenerator>(JSONData);
```

From what I've read, it seems like my error is a result of the parsing the array (the value for the property `selectedBusinessUnits`) into the desired `C#` collection.

After implementing @DavidG's suggestion, I'm still receiving the following:

```
Error converting value \"{\"guidNode\":\"some value\",\"businessUnit\":\"some value\",\"fileName\":\"some value.xlsx\"}\" 
to type 'ReportingDataSchema.CurrentBusinessUnits'. Path 'selectedBusinessUnits[0]', line 1, position 159."}    
System.Exception {Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException}
```

Prany's solution nearly got me there. I was able to modify that code to utilize the objects I already had:

```
var files = JObject.Parse(JSONData);
var recList = files.SelectToken("$..selectedBusinessUnits").ToList();

foreach (string item in recList)
{
    JObject businessUnit = JObject.Parse(item);

    CurrentBusinessUnits currentBusinessUnit = businessUnit.ToObject<CurrentBusinessUnits>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Jobject since you're using Newtonsoft. For getting values based on selectedBusinessUnits. Use below

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJson);
var recList = files.SelectToken("$..selectedBusinessUnits").ToList();
foreach (JObject item in recList)
{
   foreach (JProperty prop in item.Children())
      {
         string key = prop.Name.ToString();
         string value = prop.Value.ToString();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are trying to deserialise into the wrong type. you have specified a `Dictionary<string, List<CurrentBusinessUnits>>` but really you only need a `List<CurrentBusinessUnits>`:

```
public class EnAFileGenerator
{
    public List<CurrentBusinessUnits> SelectedBusinessUnits { get; set; }
}
```